# How do I center navbar link items using Bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I followed the w3schools documentation page for bootstrap navbars, which said to add `justify-content-center` to my navbar to center links. In addition, I followed a YouTube video which said to do the same thing, with the caveat of adding that Bootstrap class to the div class which has `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse"` however, when I add it to my code, it does not center any of the items. I only want to center the nav links and not the brand logo.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<header class="header">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-colour navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark_disabled">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">BRAND</a>

      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">

          <li class=" nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>

          <li class=" nav-item">
            <a class="navolour nav-link" href="#">About</a>
          </li>

          <li class=" nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="navolour nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Drop Down
              </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Nav Item 1</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Nav Item 2</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Nav Item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li class=" nav-item">
            <a class="navolour nav-link" href="search.php">Nav Link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eagucmh0/

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap documentation indicates the `justify-content-center` should be on the `<ul>` element - `<ul class="nav justify-content-center">`

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navs-tabs/

**Update**

Try this...

```
  <!-- ======= Header ======= -->
  <header class="header">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-colour navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark ">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">BRAND</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
          aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <!-- <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent"> -->
          <ul class="navbar-nav mb-2 mb-lg-0 justify-content-center collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <li class=" nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class=" nav-item">
              <a class="navolour nav-link" href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class=" nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="navolour nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button"
                data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Drop Down
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Nav Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Nav Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Nav Item 3</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class=" nav-item">
              <a class="navolour nav-link" href="search.php">Nav Link</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        <!-- </div> -->
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header><!-- End Header -->
```

Commented out the inner `<div>` and moved its classes and the id to the `<ul>` element.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0vm29bah/

Comment: Thanks for answering, however that still does not seem to fix the problem. I added ```justify-content-center``` to the ```<ul>``` tag like you said, which did not fix it. I've updated the jsfiddle with it here. https://jsfiddle.net/5qmuLb3z/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the `me-auto` class off the list. That pushes it over even if you use centering classes on the parent element.

See the full page demo.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<header class="header">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-colour navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark_disabled">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">BRAND</a>

      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mb-2 mb-lg-0">

          <li class=" nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>

          <li class=" nav-item">
            <a class="navolour nav-link" href="#">About</a>
          </li>

          <li class=" nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="navolour nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Drop Down
              </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Nav Item 1</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Nav Item 2</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Nav Item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li class=" nav-item">
            <a class="navolour nav-link" href="search.php">Nav Link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```